# How can I detect broken stored procedures after a schema change?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have a database with up to hundreds of table and hundreds of stored procedures.
The database schema has been altered (e.x: some tables/columns have been renamed, some columns have been deleted/added etc).

The question is: how to detect the procedures that have been impacted by those changes (that produce error on execution), **without actually executing them**, because executing them one by one is a lot of manual and time-consuming work?

### Edit

> The closest solution I've found until now is this:
> sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities. A query like `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.procedure_name', 'OBJECT');`
> returns an error if procedure *procedure_name* is broken by those
> changes.
>
> So, I can get the names of all procedures and run the upper
> query in a loop for each procedure name, and do some kind of logic in
> there, like printing the procedure name in
> case of error.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query, mind you that this can also list false positives in certain cases.

**Query to get a list of `invalid` objects:**

```
select QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
       o.type_desc,
       ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
         + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
from   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
  left join sys.objects o on sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
where  (is_ambiguous = 0)
and  (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
       + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)
     ) IS NULL)
order by ProblemObject, MissingReferencedObject
```

more info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

Other useful queries when you are redesigning your scheme can be this

**query to find procedures that are called from others:**

```
declare @t table (procname varchar(200), called_in varchar(200))
declare @ProcName varchar(200)

declare crProcs cursor local FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY for
         select distinct
                o.name as procedure_name
         from   sys.sql_modules m
           inner join sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
         where o.Type = 'P'

open crProcs
fetch next from crProcs into @ProcName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
     insert into @t (procname, called_in)
     select @ProcName,
            o.name
     from   sys.sql_modules m
       inner join sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
     where  m.definition Like '%' + @ProcName + '%'
     group by o.name

     fetch next from crProcs into @ProcName
end 
close crProcs
deallocate crProcs

select * 
from   @t t
where  1 < (select count(1) from @t t2 where t2.procname = t.procname )
```

**query to find all objects where another object is being used:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%MyTableThatIWantToChangeTheScheme%'
```

Comment: Seems quite sophisticated and promising. It already found me plenty of broken procedures until now. Now I just have to check if there are any false positives like you said.

Comment: @Ergis Well I hope it will save you some time. Glad if I could help

Comment: @Ergis False positives can be when a procedure needs data from another database in certain rare case, or when custom types are used. If you dont use that you will have no false positives